# Vigenere Cipher

Tags: c, vigenere, cs50

i am facing the problem while running the below code designed for vigenere cipher.even after going thoroughly i am not able to debug the problem. it is showing the error:killed by server.please help.

```
 /**
 * 
 * vigenere.c
 * 
 * Abhishek kumar
 * encrypts entered string using vigenere cipher
 * */
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <cs50.h>
 #include <ctype.h>
 #include <string.h>

 int main(int argc, string argv[] )
 {
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: /home/cs50/pset2/vigenere <keyword>");
        return 1;
    }

    if (argc == 2)
    {   string key = argv[1];
        for(int k = 0,l = strlen(key);k < l; k++)
        {
            if(!isalpha(key[k]))
            {
                printf("Keyword must only contain letters A-Z and a-z");
                exit(1);
            } 

        }


        string txt = GetString();
        int i = 0,j = 0,c = 0;
        int n = strlen(txt);
        int m = strlen(key);
        while(i < n)
        {
            if (isupper(txt[i]))
            {
                if(isupper(key[j]))
                {
                    c = ((((int) txt[i] - 65 + (int) key[j] -65)%26) + 65);
                    printf("%c", (char) c);
                    i++;
                    j++;
                }
                if(islower(key[j]))
                {
                    c = ((((int) txt[i] - 65 + (int) key[j] -97)%26) + 65);
                    printf("%c", (char) c);
                    i++;
                    j++;
                }

            }
            else if (islower(txt[i]))
            {
                if(isupper(key[j]))
                {
                    c = ((((int) txt[i] - 97 + (int) key[j] -65)%26) + 97);
                    printf("%c", (char) c);
                    i++;
                }
                if(islower(key[j]))
                {
                    c = ((((int) txt[i] - 97 + (int) key[j] -97)%26) + 97);
                    printf("%c", (char) c);
                    j++;
                }


            }
            else
            {
                printf("%c",txt[i]);
                i++;

            }
            if (j == m-1)
            {
                j = 0;
            }
        }




    }
 }
```

below are some of the test cases in which it is failing.

```
:) vigenere.c exists
:) vigenere.c compiles
:( encrypts "a" as "a" using "a" as keyword
   \ killed by server
:( encrypts "world, say hello!" as "xoqmd, rby gflkp!" using "baz" as keyword
   \ killed by server
:( encrypts "BaRFoo" as "CaQGon" using "BaZ" as keyword
   \ expected output, but not "CGSFpp"
:( encrypts "BARFOO" as "CAQGON" using "BAZ" as keyword
   \ expected output, but not "CASFPO"
:) handles lack of argv[1]
:) handles argc > 2
:) rejects "Hax0r2" as keyword
```

Comment: Please add some sample input and desired output.

Comment: please ask a question

Comment: edited,checkout now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `islower(txt[i])` section, you fail to increment `i` and `j` in all cases.  In the place where you don't increment `i`, i.e. where the first character of the key and the text are both lower case, you end up with an infinite loop.

In the `isupper(txt[i])` section, you increment `i` and `j` in the `isupper(key[j])` part, then you enter the `islower(key[j])` part because you use `if` instead of `else if`.

For both of the above, change `if(islower(key[j]))` to `else if(islower(key[j]))`, and move `j++` and the `printf` after each inner `if` block.  As for `i`, change `while` to a `for` and increment `i` as part of that.

When checking to see if you should reset `j`, you're off by 1.  `m-1` is a valid index for `key` so you don't want to reset yet.  Do it when `j == m`.

Also, replace the ASCII codes with the actual characters they represent so it's more clear what you're doing.  The casts aren't needed either.

```
    for (i=0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (isupper(txt[i]))
        {
            if(isupper(key[j]))
            {
                c = (((txt[i] - 'A' + key[j] -'A')%26) + 'A');
            } 
            else if(islower(key[j]))
            {
                c = (((txt[i] - 'A' + key[j] -'a')%26) + 'A');
            }
            printf("%c", c);
            j++;
        }
        else if (islower(txt[i]))
        {
            if(isupper(key[j]))
            {
                c = (((txt[i] - 'a' + key[j] -'A')%26) + 'a');
            } 
            else if(islower(key[j]))
            {
                c = (((txt[i] - 'a' + key[j] -'a')%26) + 'a');
            }
            printf("%c", c);
            j++;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%c",txt[i]);
        }
        if (j == m)
        {
            j = 0;
        }
    }
```